# How to remove what appears to be a locking nut from a ceiling fixture

Tags: lighting

My daughter is trying to change the bulbs in a flush mount ceiling fixture in her apartment.  There appears to be some kind of locking nut/mechanism under the nipple that she cannot remove.  Does anyone have any idea how to remove this so she can remove the glass?[image: flush mount fixture]

Comment: somebody lost the original nut ... they had that nut in their parts box ... it is a nut from wooden furniture ... it is not a locking nut

Answer (score 2):

Just a plain supporting nut/holder.  Almost any type of pliers will turn it , to undo.  Hold glass housing as you are undoing it.

Might also be able to use fingers if you push up slightly on the glass.

Does not seem to be any special locking mechanism to it, very seldom is.

Comment: I agree.  If you can't get a grip on the nut with fingers or pliers try gripping the nipple, it almost certainly can be unscrewed from the fixture at its top end.  It's possible the nut is rusted onto the nipple a bit and the other end of the nipple will turn more easily.  If it does, go with it.

Comment: I think a long-nose plier will be easier to get to it. Also, keep one hand gently pushing the glass fixture for ease of turning the thin metal piece.